# Is there a way to re-define a function bound to $ctrl outside of AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my DOM, I have this element which contains `ng-click="$ctrl.goToHome()` which is bound to the logo of my site. The element is being created by a third-party app made in AngularJS. See full element below:

```
<img ng-if="::!$ctrl.config.url" ng-click="$ctrl.goToHome()" class="ct-logo" ng-src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/logo.png" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/logo.png">
```

However, this function is not working probably because the function is not defined. I'm not sure where to define it. Is there some way to re-define the goToHome() function? In other words, is it possible to re-bind the function using jQuery or JS? If so, what would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So basically, `$ctrl` is its own scope, kind of like its own world, every method defined inside of it does not exist outside, it seems like you are trying to use `$ctrl.goToHome()` outside of the `$ctrl` scope.

If you want to `goToHome()` method to be available outside of the `$ctrl` scope.

You could do either of the two

- You could either extract out the `goToHome()` method to maybe a factory and then call it in whatever scope you want to use it. That way `goToHome()` always does one thing.

```
const app = angular.module("app", []);

const goToHomeHandler = function() {
    return {
        goToHome: function() {
            alert('go Home');
        }
    };
};

app.factory('goToHomeHandler', goToHomeHandler);

app.controller("personController", function($scope, goToHomeHandler) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.goToHome = function () {
        goToHomeHandler.goToHome();
    }
});

app.controller("personController2", function($scope, goToHomeHandler) {
    $scope.firstName = "Second John";
    $scope.lastName = "Second Doe";
    $scope.goToHome = function () {
        goToHomeHandler.goToHome();
    }
});
```

- Another option, maybe not the best is to define the `goToHome()` method on the `$windows` scope, that way it's accessible anywhere.

I added a little example below

As you can see, even though the `test()` method was created in `personController`, it can be used in `personController2` as long it is accessed via the `$windows` scope

```
    const app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("personController", function($scope, $window) {
    $window.goToHome = function() {
      alert('yoyo');
    }
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.goToHome = function () {
        $window.goToHome();
    }
});

app.controller("personController2", function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.firstName = "Second John";
    $scope.lastName = "Second Doe";
    $scope.goToHome = function () {
        $window.goToHome();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not applying the Angular myself, as I mentioned, it's coming from a third party app module. So basically, I should install AngularJS and try to redefine it? Which version AngularJS should I use?

Comment: If there is ```ng-click``` in your code, there is AngularJS in your codebase already. If you cannot figure that out, you can maybe create a new JS method that has the same functionality as the ```$ctrl.goToHome()```